# Add a line break automatically after comma in JSON file?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a JSON file automatically generated from my PHP laravel backend, it's just an array converted to JSON format, problem is I'd like to have a the JSON file row by row instead of this ugly mess of serialized data...

This is how my JSON file looks:

```
[{"cityName":"Toronto","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"Montreal","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"Calgary","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"Ottawa","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"Edmonton","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"Mississauga","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"North York",
```

If you past it into your IDE (mine is Visual Studio Code) you will see how ugly it looks, because of it syntax hilighting doesn't even work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) has a `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option. Something like this should work:

```
$json = '[{"cityName":"Toronto","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"Montreal","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"Calgary","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"Ottawa","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"Edmonton","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"},{"cityName":"Mississauga","provinceOrState":"Canada","country":"Canada"}]';

$data = json_decode($json);
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo "<pre>$json</pre>";
```

This results in an output like this:

```
[
    {
        "cityName": "Toronto",
        "provinceOrState": "Canada",
        "country": "Canada"
    },
    {
        "cityName": "Montreal",
        "provinceOrState": "Canada",
        "country": "Canada"
    },
    ......
]
```

Comment: json_decode should not need any changes. Prettified JSON is still proper JSON. Now, if it’s pseudo-JSON.. although json_decode doesn’t even support those cases appropriately.

Comment: @user2864740: I tested the code, and you're right, no extra options for `json_decode()` are needed.

Comment: adding header application/json and prettify will prettiify the json encoded

Comment: @Jerson: Yes, most browsers will recognize that Content-Type header and format the JSON. This could be a good solution as well, depending on the circumstances.